# How to use diffrent proxy_pass ports for the same domain depending on the url scheme (ws:// or http://) in nginx

Tags: nginx, devops, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a single subdomain (say api.xyz.com)

I have two services -

1. an HTTP REST API, (say on port 3000)
2. a web-socket service. (say on port 5000)

I want to use the same subdomain but use it with two services depending on the scheme

for example

if I use `http://api.xyz.com` --> it proxy_passes to  port 3000

and

if I use `ws://api.xyz.com` --> it proxy_passes to port 5000

can someone please point me in the right direction? (right now, I am using two separate subdomains api.xyz.com and ws.xyz.com)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

```
server {

    server_name api.xyz.com;
    location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

            if ($http_upgrade = "websocket") {
                    add_header  X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;
                    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            }

            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
 }
```

So you have to check the headers and proxy_pass to appropriate port.